# CocoaPods: Installing a pod while excluding certain components

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to install the mParticle_Extended pod. However it contains an AppBoy component that is conflicting with another pod in my Podfile called Appboy-iOS-SDK.

My question is how to specify that I want to install mParticle_Extended, but without the AppBoy component so that I don't have a linker conflict between the two pods.

Thanks!

Comment: You can unlink one of them in the post install section of the podfile.

Comment: Cool, if you could post how to do it in the answer

Comment: By the way, it looks like mParticle_Extended is depcrecated and we should be using mParticle-iOS-SDK instead

Answer (score 0):

According to https://cocoapods.org/?q=mparticle, you can add `pod 'mParticle-iOS-SDK/mParticle', '~> 5'` in your Podfile to install mParticle only. You can also specify the kits you want to install through mParticles by something like `pod 'mParticle-iOS-SDK', :subspecs => ['Appboy', 'BranchMetrics', 'Localytics'], '~> 5'`.